# Upgrade to Angular 12 & Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, build, google-chrome-devtools

I have upgraded an Angular 6 project to Angular 12 with .NET framework.
I'm facing 2 issues at the moment.

1)

I have specified builds commands in package.json as:

```
"prodbuild": "ng build --configuration production --aot=true --output-hashing none",
"build": "ng build --output-hashing none",
```

and I'm able to compile using ng build --output-hashing none. However, I'm not being able to debug the code using Chorme dev tools, the source displays from Webpack and not the directory structure of project. The code I'm changing in ts files is not updating in dev tools. I have tried to clear cache, page refresh, but it is not helping.

2. I've been using earlier

   ng build --watch

what has replaced this? This was very convenient to update code and refresh in browser.

Here is my angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyProj": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "xlsx",
              "rxjs/BehaviorSubject",
              "rxjs/add/observable/throw",
              "rxjs/add/operator/catch",
              "rxjs/Observable",
              "rxjs/operators/map",
              "rxjs/operators/tap"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProj:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyProj:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyProj:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyProj-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyProj:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyProj",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng build` compiles with production configuration by default now.

Try `ng build --watch --configuration development` or `ng serve`

Comment: I set that command in package.json and also ran on command prompt. I get: An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace.

Comment: Which configurations are defined in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: added angular.json to post

Comment: Ok, with your configuration `ng build --watch` should already work.
I've created a fresh project with the Angular CLI and copied your settings from the build section (except styles & scripts). However, everything works fine and I can't reproduce your issue.